# Dynamic Facebook sharer thumbnail (oct 2013 update)

Tags: javascript, jquery, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sharer

as you would probably know, this October Facebook removed the support to the p[images] parameter of its sharer.

So for example this:

`https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?
s=100&p[title]=Abstract+Photo+1
&p[summary]=Lorem+ipsum+dolor+sit+amet
&p[images][0]=http//:www.website.com/an-image.jpg`

won't work anymore.

I have a jQuery lightbox with a dynamic sharer button and this is a huge problem.
Following the Facebook documentation, now the FB scraper handle only the og:image meta. But how we can set a dynamic thumbnail only with javascript?

Comment: You can’t. Facebook’s Open Graph is based on URLs to identify its objects, so everything you want to have individually shared needs its own individual URL as well.

Comment: Yes, is what I thought too. But there isn't any way to use a custom image?

I guess I'm not the only one who used the [images] within a javascript plugin. Has FB cut us off?

Comment: Well, for your own pages using og:image is quite custom, isn’t it? If you want a custom image _per user_, then you can only use the Feed dialog, that still accepts the `picture` parameter. (But with that you are limited to posting to the user’s own wall, or _one_ user id that has been determined beforehand.)

Answer (score 0):

So, the CBroe suggestion about the *facebook.com/dialog/feed* was the right path to follow.
The only way to get rid of the facebook sharer update and images is to:

1 - create a facebook APP ("website with facebook access" type) and use your main website URL in the mandatory field

---

2 - Go in the main website root and create an html file. It will be the redirect target and contains the script required to close the popup. Put within this code:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.close()
    </script>
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

---

3 - in your javascript plugin use an URL like this replacing the placeholders with variables:

`https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?app_id=THE-APP-ID&display=popup&name=THE-TITLE&description=THE-DESCRIPTION&picture=PICTURE-URL&link=PAGE-LINK&redirect_uri=URL-TO-THE-HTML-FILE-ON-YOUR-WEBSITE`